# Does Platform Event count against API Limit if we are publish the events to Non Salesforce System

Tags: platform-event, publish-subscribe

Does Platform Event count against API Limit  if we are publish the events to Non Salesforce System...

As far i have understood,Platform Event pubiish doesnt count against API limit in an org.
If we are using REST API in spite of PE,it would count.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Platform Events have their [own limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm) and are not counted against the org [API limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm). The org API limits are for inbound traffic while Platform Events are out-bound.

Apex-based Platform Event Subscribers do not count towards API limits, but the events themselves do count towards the Event Publishing limits.

CometD-based Platform Event Subscribers do not count towards API limits but do count towards the Event Delivery limits.

Clearly if the **external** (CometD) subscriber needs data that is not part of the Event itself then it must naturally fetch that data separately via an API call, and this will count against those API daily limits.

Comment: What happens if a subscriber is subscribed to that platform Event.Will it count against API limit because subscriber will pull those Platform event details from salesforce.